# What's the status of Ethereum Light Client?

Tags: synchronization, light-clients

Is there any stable Ethereum Light Client? Which one is production ready? What's the status and the roadmap?
Moreover, I'm looking for some metrics related to a Light Client:

1. Runtime resources usage (memory, cpu)
2. How much time it takes to sync (from genesis) on a mid level-mobile device (let's say we have max 300MB RAM available)?
3. How much time it takes to re-sync after 1 week break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Resource usage tends to be very light for light clients. You can usually stay under 300 MB of RAM, and CPU utilization is just a few cycles to verify block headers every 15 seconds or so when new blocks come out.
2. Light clients don't generally sync from genesis. Each build of the client ships with a checkpoint for the network, and it only has to sync forward from that checkpoint. Geth builds come out once or twice a month, so if you keep up to date you won't have to sync more than a few weeks, which even on a mobile device shouldn't take more than a few minutes if you have adequate peers.
3. As I said with point two, you won't generally be syncing from genesis with a light client, so a fresh sync isn't really much different from a resync with a 1 week break - probably just a few minutes.

The problem with light clients is finding full nodes to peer with. Light clients depend entirely on full nodes accepting light clients as peers. Many full nodes don't accept light client peers at all, and the ones that do are often at capacity. In my experience, it's not uncommon to start up a light client and wait twenty minutes before it finds a peer, then randomly lose the one peer that we had and become unable to stay synced.

Comment: how about the clients? Is Geth LC production ready?

Comment: After checking in other places (gitter go-ethereum) it seams that Geth LC is production ready. But the main problem is to find peers who will serve the light client (currently full nodes are rejecting or limiting the connections to light clients).